# Thymeleaf does not resolve fragment in my app when I call it in brackets. Why is that?

Tags: java, spring, templates, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to spring and thymeleaf.
I have a spring-boot web application with thymeleaf, and I encountered a problem.
This line works perfectly:

```
<footer th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer">Footer</footer>
```

But when I write brackets around it, as in the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#including-template-fragments), I get an error.

```
<footer th:replace="~{fragments/footer :: footer}">Footer</footer>
```

Error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Error resolving template "~{fragments/footer", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (index:11)

So what can be the problem, I use the default spring boot configuration.
pom.xml :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Log:

> 2017-03-01 22:47:51.585 ERROR 4014 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "index": Error resolving template "~{fragments/footer", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (index:11)
>   2017-03-01 22:47:51.591 ERROR 4014 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "~{fragments/footer", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (index:11)] with root cause
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "~{fragments/footer", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (index:11)
>       at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.thymeleaf.standard.fragment.StandardFragment.extractFragment(StandardFragment.java:202) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardFragmentHandlingAttrProcessor.computeFragment(AbstractStandardFragmentHandlingAttrProcessor.java:72) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractFragmentHandlingAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractFragmentHandlingAttrProcessor.java:63) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using thymeleaf 2.  Fragment expressions are new to thymeleaf 3.

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html#fragment-expressions

Comment: Thank you, I thought spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf will use thymeleaf 3.
I added this to my pom.xml and it works fine.
`<properties>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>`