# Error resolving fragment: "${h3}": template or fragment could not be resolved

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Recently, I learned Thymeleaf, all the time using official documentation. I imitate the official documentation examples to rewrite one, but I can't run it correctly.

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving fragment: "${h3}": template or fragment could not be resolved (template: "one" - line 18, col 18)
```

This is my code, in one file

```
  <td>

        <div th:fragment="copy(h3,h4)">
            &copy; 2011 The Good Thymes Virtual Grocery
            <div th:replace="${h3}">洛阳</div>
            <div>copy</div>
            <div th:replace="${h4}">月明</div>
        </div>
        <div th:replace="this::copy(~{::h3},~{::h4})">
            <h2>梦里寻欢;</h2>
            <h3 class="one">你好</h3>
            <h4 class="two">号码</h4>
        </div>

    </td>
```

please guide me through the error.

Comment: Where is your `one.html`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thymeleaf does not resolve fragment in my app when I call it in brackets. Why is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542861/thymeleaf-does-not-resolve-fragment-in-my-app-when-i-call-it-in-brackets-why-is)

Comment: What version of Thymeleaf are you using?

Comment: I eventually know the error , I placed them in one file ,that's the thing , I test the example int different html page  and it can run correctly.